# How to center text in dropdown button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can i center the text in the selected option of dropdown button using Bootstrap-select?

I did managed to center all options when the dropdown is activated, but still dont know how to center the selected option.

Viewing the buttons in [Bootstrap-Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), all selected options in the buttons are floated to left.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center all options use this css

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li > a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

To center selected option, use this

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .btn .filter-option {
    text-align: center; /* to override text-align: left; */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yvpsb/